# Spring JPA sql-pool - Reset (readOnly) on connection on a few table

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, orm

In my logs file, while querying a certain table it logs:

`2022-06-07 17:16:31,404 [pool-10-thread-69] DEBUG [PoolBase] [REF=""] - sql-pool - Reset (readOnly) on connection ConnectionID:9 ClientConnectionId: 11c28ad4-4ceb-486e-952a-789675916ca9`

I can't find it online that what does sql-pool - Reset (readOnly) on connection ConnectionID mean.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [this code of Hikari](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/PoolBase.java), it means that the Connection Pool is resetting the state of `readOnly` configuration. It can be from `true` to `false` or vice versa. These are the list of reset states:

```
private static final String[] RESET_STATES = {"readOnly", "autoCommit", "isolation", "catalog", "netTimeout", "schema"};
```

I get rid of this by setting the `readOnly` as `false` in the `application.properties` because in my case it reset from `true` to `false`. So when I set it to `false` in the properties, will prevent it from getting reset

```
spring.readonly.datasource.hikari.read-only=false
```